# Juniper NETCONF RPC - No data returned

Tags: xml, rpc, juniper, netconf

I am trying to send a custom XML RPC to my Juniper VM. The command is the following:

netconf-console --host 192.168.1.100 --port 830 --user xxxx --password xxxx --rpc junos-get-interfaces.xml

```
<nc:get-config xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
<nc:source>
<nc:running/>
</nc:source>
<nc:filter type="xpath" select="/interfaces">
</nc:filter>
</nc:get-config>
```

The custom RPC is trying to filter the running configuration, to just retrieve the interfaces stanza. But i am getting the following response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns:junos="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/12.1R1/junos" xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="urn:uuid:f0b4fd48-fcb5-4e03-815b-961a19a9b525">
<data>
</data>
</rpc-reply>
```

However, there is configuration under the Interfaces stanza on the box. Any ideas whats going on ? I have also tried to use xpath in the netconf-console CLI command, but its saying the server does not support it

netconf-console --host 192.168.1.100 --port 830 --user xxxx --password xxxx --get-config /native/interfaces
Operation failed: MissingCapabilityError - Server does not support [:xpath]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XPath** is **not** a valid filter type for get-config.

`<filter> — Enclose the <configuration> tag element. The mandatory type attribute indicates the kind of syntax used to represent the requested configuration elements; the` ***`only`*** `acceptable value is subtree.`

https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/tag-summary/netconf-get-config.html

You can use the filter type subtree instead as outlined below.

*NOTE: GET-CONF does not have an attribute for inheritance. If you need to pull what would be the final configuration, i.e. you are using the "Groups" stanza, you will need to use GET-CONFIGURATION. I will show the difference in an additional output below.*
https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/tag-summary/junos-xml-protocol-get-configuration.html

***Contents of get-interfaces.xml using get-conf***

```
<get-config>
    <source>
        <running/>
    </source>
    <filter type="subtree">
        <configuration>
            <interfaces/>
        </configuration>
    </filter>
</get-config>
```

***Run your command at the targeted host:***

```
netconf-console --host 10.49.162.162 --port 830 --user root --password xxxx --rpc get-interfaces.xml
```

***Sample output from get-conf:***

```
root@Ubuntu-Server:~# netconf-console --host 10.49.162.162 --port 830 --user root --password Embe1mpls --rpc get-interfaces.xml 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns:junos="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/18.3I0/junos" xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="urn:uuid:ae0be5f0-4f9d-45fa-b92f-c161d2a92f2b">
<data>
<configuration xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/xnm/1.1/xnm" junos:commit-seconds="1608495419" junos:commit-localtime="2020-12-20 12:16:59 PST" junos:commit-user="root">
    <interfaces>
        <interface>
            <name>xe-0/0/0</name>
            <unit>
                <name>0</name>
                <family>
                    <inet>
                        <address>
                            <name>172.20.0.12/32</name>
                        </address>
                    </inet>
                </family>
            </unit>
        </interface>
        <interface>
            <name>xe-0/0/1</name>
            <unit>
                <name>0</name>
                <family>
                    <inet>
                        <address>
                            <name>172.20.20.0/32</name>
                        </address>
                    </inet>
                </family>
            </unit>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
</configuration>
</data>
</rpc-reply>
```

***Contents of get-interfaces.xml using get-configuration with inheritance***

```
<get-configuration inherit="inherit">
    <configuration>
        <interfaces/>
    </configuration>
</get-configuration>
```

***Sample output from get-configuration: [Note all the additional interfaces that are inherited on the same host]***

```
root@Ubuntu-Server:~# netconf-console --host 10.49.162.162 --port 830 --user root --password xxxx --rpc get-interfaces.xml 
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns:junos="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/18.3I0/junos" xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="urn:uuid:92751ca5-8d1f-449c-a3e8-10aba7be249c">
<configuration xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/xnm/1.1/xnm" junos:changed-seconds="1608495419" junos:changed-localtime="2020-12-20 12:16:59 PST">
    <interfaces>
        <interface>
            <name>xe-0/0/0</name>
            <unit>
                <name>0</name>
                <family>
                    <inet>
                        <address>
                            <name>172.20.0.12/32</name>
                        </address>
                    </inet>
                </family>
            </unit>
        </interface>
        <interface>
            <name>xe-0/0/1</name>
            <unit>
                <name>0</name>
                <family>
                    <inet>
                        <address>
                            <name>172.20.20.0/32</name>
                        </address>
                    </inet>
                </family>
            </unit>
        </interface>
        <interface>
            <name>lo0</name>
            <unit>
                <name>0</name>
                <family>
                    <inet>
                        <address>
                            <name>128.49.162.162/32</name>
                            <primary/>
                        </address>
                    </inet>
                    <iso>
                        <address>
                            <name>47.0005.80ff.f800.0000.0108.0001.1280.4916.2162.00</name>
                        </address>
                    </iso>
                    <inet6>
                        <address>
                            <name>abcd::128:49:162:162/128</name>
                            <primary/>
                        </address>
                    </inet6>
                </family>
            </unit>
        </interface>
        <interface>
            <name>em0</name>
            <unit>
                <name>0</name>
                <family>
                    <inet>
                        <address>
                            <name>10.49.162.162/19</name>
                        </address>
                    </inet>
                </family>
            </unit>
        </interface>
        <interface>
            <name>em1</name>
            <unit>
                <name>0</name>
                <family>
                    <inet>
                        <address>
                            <name>169.254.0.2/24</name>
                        </address>
                    </inet>
                </family>
            </unit>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
</configuration>
</rpc-reply>
```

***Note: to help find the filter levels the " | display xml " command can be run on the host to help identify the proper tag***

```
root@vqfx-leaf-01> show configuration interfaces | display xml | display inheritance 
<rpc-reply xmlns:junos="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/18.3I0/junos">
    <configuration junos:commit-seconds="1608495419" junos:commit-localtime="2020-12-20 12:16:59 PST" junos:commit-user="root">
            <interfaces>
                <interface>
                    <name>xe-0/0/0</name>
                    <unit>
                        <name>0</name>
                        <family>
                            <inet>
                                <address>
                                    <name>172.20.0.12/32</name>
                                </address>
                            </inet>
                        </family>
                    </unit>
                </interface>
                <interface>
                    <name>xe-0/0/1</name>
                    <unit>
                        <name>0</name>
                        <family>
                            <inet>
                                <address>
                                    <name>172.20.20.0/32</name>
                                </address>
                            </inet>
                        </family>
                    </unit>
                </interface>
                <interface>
                    <name>lo0</name>
                    <unit>
                        <name>0</name>
                        <family>
                            <inet>
                                <address>
                                    <name>128.49.162.162/32</name>
                                    <primary/>
                                </address>
                            </inet>
                            <iso>
                                <address>
                                    <name>47.0005.80ff.f800.0000.0108.0001.1280.4916.2162.00</name>
                                </address>
                            </iso>
                            <inet6>
                                <address>
                                    <name>abcd::128:49:162:162/128</name>
                                    <primary/>
                                </address>
                            </inet6>
                        </family>
                    </unit>
                </interface>
                <interface>
                    <name>em0</name>
                    <unit>              
                        <name>0</name>
                        <family>
                            <inet>
                                <address>
                                    <name>10.49.162.162/19</name>
                                </address>
                            </inet>
                        </family>
                    </unit>
                </interface>
                <interface>
                    <name>em1</name>
                    <unit>
                        <name>0</name>
                        <family>
                            <inet>
                                <address>
                                    <name>169.254.0.2/24</name>
                                </address>
                            </inet>
                        </family>
                    </unit>
                </interface>
            </interfaces>
    </configuration>
    <cli>
        <banner>{master:0}</banner>
    </cli>
</rpc-reply>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use `--get-config` with `--xpath` via the netconf-console CLI command, you can do something like this:

```
netconf-console --host 192.168.1.100 --port 830 --user xxxx --password xxxx --get-config --xpath /native/interfaces
```